# jQuery, is there a way to set anchor in URL after form submitting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

For example, I have tabulators (bootstrap, tabpanel) which changes the url, adding #tab1, #tab2, ... as Im clicking on them. Lets say I do a submit from #tab1, and want to jump to #tab2, how to do that? All I have is:

```
.
.
.
$(formObj).submit();
return false;
```

the action of form is empty (`<form method="post">`)

Comment: See if any of [these answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-using-jquery) help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `.tab("show")` function, [as specified in the Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs), to show the tab that you want after the form submission.

For example, if your form is in `#tab1` and you want to move to `#tab2` after the form is submitted, you could do it like this (change `#myTabs` for the `id` of the tab list that you are using):

```
$(formObj).submit();
$('#myTabs a[href="#tab2"]').tab('show')
return false;
```